# функция show не записывают переменную btn.i в объект btn

Tags: javascript

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    'use strict';
    let infoHeader = document.querySelector('.info-header'),
        infoHeaderTab = document.querySelectorAll('.info-header-tab'),
        infoTabcontent = document.querySelectorAll('.info-tabcontent'),
        block;


    function start(cout) {
        for (let i = cout; i < infoTabcontent.length; i++) {
            infoTabcontent[i].classList.remove('show');
            infoTabcontent[i].classList.add('hide'); 
        }
    }

    let btn = {
        i: block
    };

    start(1);
    startBtn(0);

    function startBtn(cout) {
        btn.i = cout;
    }

    function show(cout) {
        infoTabcontent[cout].classList.remove('hide');
        infoTabcontent[cout].classList.add('show');
        btn.i = cout;
    }

    infoHeader.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        let pass = event.target;
        if (pass && pass.classList.contains('info-header-tab')) {
            for (var i = 0; i < infoHeaderTab.length; i++) {
                if (pass == infoHeaderTab[i]) {
                    start(0);
                    show(i);
                    break;
                }
            } 
        }
    });




    // Modal block

    let descriptionBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.description-btn');

    descriptionBtns[btn.i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        overlay.style.display = 'block';
        this.classList.add('more-splash');
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }); 

    popupClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
        overlay.style.display = 'none';
        this.classList.remove('more-splash');
        document.body.style.overflow = '';
    });

    console.log(btn.i);

});
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не записывает? Приведенный код в месте `console.log(btn.i);` выведет вполне ожидаемую единицу.

Comment: выводит undefined

Comment: а у меня выводит `1`. Отредактируй вопрос с помощью кнопки [edit] и добавь в него [mcve]. Для этого можно воспользоваться [сниппетами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/186999) которые можно запустить непосредственно в вопросе.

Comment: скинул весь код. infoHeader вызывает функцию show, которая меняет значение i, но она это не делает, как был 0 так и остался.

Comment: тогда как правильно вытащить переменную i из infoHeader?

Comment: То есть ты спрашиваешь: почему при выводе переменной _до_ того как ей присвоили новое значение она показывает старое?